# Automount problem when mount point in user home directory

Tags: boot, fstab, automount

A correctly structured `fstab` entry exists for a /dev/sda2 partition, which is slated to mount at ~/DataStore.  However, even after throwing the kitchen sink at the issue, the partition *never* automounts upon bootup.  Only after I login and execute `sudo mount /dev/sda2` does the partition mount.

Question:  Is a mount point in a user's home directory problematic?  In other words, does automounting in a home directory necessarily fail when a user is not yet logged in?

For reference, below are the contents of the `fstab` file:

```
UUID=62b51a68-49fa-4ae0-816e-01c0755d2bb4  / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1

# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=547f8a6b-f7b8-4ff9-b936-5972d75c557d none swap sw 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a /home/pete/DataStore auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: Try `UUID=e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a /home/pete/DataStore auto defaults,nofail 0 0` changing auto to ext4 or ntfs-3g or whatever.

Comment: Regrettably, your suggestion falls under the "kitchen sink" umbrella.  I've tried this, but the issue remains.

Comment: You might add that info to your question.

Comment: @PeteJanda -- capitalization is significant, be sure folder names are identical for your mount point

Comment: @PeteJanda if you changed the mount to /mnt or /media, does it mount properly at boot time?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, those mount points enable proper automounting at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

I assume (because `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` exists) that you have an Encrypted Home Directory, like I do.

On ***MY*** system,

```
$ df -h | grep /home
df: /run/user/1003/gvfs: Transport endpoint is not connected
/dev/sdb6          289G  243G   31G  89% /home
/home/w3/.Private  289G  243G   31G  89% /home/w3

$ mount|grep /home
/dev/sdb6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/home/.ecryptfs/w3/.Private on /home/w3 type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=e377cfa845240aa1,ecryptfs_sig=5fa903fe1f605483,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

because I'm logged in, my unencrypted `HOME` directory is **decrypted** and mounted on `/home/w3`.

On your system, at the time that auto mounts are done (in `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh`), you are NOT logged in, your `HOME` directory is NOT decrypted nor mounted, and your mount point `/home/pete/DataStore` does not exist. `mount` is sad.

Remove the `auto`, and drop a little script/`.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` to do the mount after you log in.

Comment: If their home was encrypted, wouldn't you see that in their fstab?

Comment: @heynnema -- not if it isn't a separate partition

Comment: @ravery But you can't encrypt /boot can you? So wouldn't you see that in fstab? I guess what I'm saying is that I see a normal mount for /, which looks like it's not encrypted, so how could /home be encrypted, unless as you say, a separate entry (for a separate partition) in fstab was made for it, and show that it was encrypted. I'm questioning waltinator's assumption.

Comment: @heynnema -- the folder  /home/ can be encrypted, or even /home/pete/. encrypting does not require a different partition. ie there can be an encrypted folder that is mounted to /home when decrypted

Comment: @ravery I'm still learning this topic... so... are you saying, that with the fstab **as it is shown**, they still can have an encrypted /home?

Comment: yes, I believe so .... I have encrypted folders, that have independent mount points when decrypted. the process should also be applicable to /home or at least with /home/pete/

Comment: @Waltinator - `mount` is no longer sad.  Many thanks.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this issue and doesn't want to learn .desktop file formats, here is my  implementation of Waltinator's fix:

1. Create a .config/autostart directory if not present
2. Create a mountDataStore.desktop file with the following:
`[Desktop Entry]`
`Type=Application`
`Name=MountDataStore`
`NoDisplay=true`
`Terminal=false`
`Exec=/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2`